# how to use jstl library in eclipse

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

i tried to add taglib files in eclipse in j2ee dynamic web project and executed a small program

```
 <%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

 <html>
 <head>
 <title>
 <c:out value="tata"></c:out>
 </title>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="white">
 <h3>

  </h3>
  <p>
   </body>  
  </html>
```

Here i am getting

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV

as an error can any one help

Comment: Put your mouse above the `[jstl]` tag below your question and wait until a black box shows. Then click therein the *info* link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `standard.jar` in your project.

Comment: sir i added jstl.jar in web-inf/lib and i added c.tld in web-inf.is that fine

Comment: @satheesh: No you will require standard.jar. To work with jstl you require both jar: jstl.jar and standard.jar.

Comment: where can i get standard.jar please help me out

Comment: @satheesh: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/STUVWXYZ/Downloadjakartastandard112jar.htm

Comment: @satheesh: Put it in `WEB-INF/lib` folder. Same place where other jars resides.